# How to Calculate an Infinitely Repeating Percent

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

How do you calculate the percentage of a number in an infinitely repeating function?

Suppose I'm doing an experiment where the inputs cost 100, and there's a 95% chance of success. To figure the average cost of success, I take 100 plus I allow for the 5% chance of failure. That's 5% x 100, or another 5.

Except that after each failure, the next round isn't guaranteed to succeed: it has a 95% chance of success, too. So that first failure really costs me 5 plus 5% of 5, which totals 5.25. But since the next round also has a 5% of failure, I should really be adding another 5% on top of that, and so on, forever.

What's the correct way to write out the calculation for this infinite series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are taking about is related to geometric distributions, so looking into that would help you a lot. Jumping just to your question though, would be the following:

100 * (.05 + .05^2 + .05^3 + ...)

It turns out this (an infinite geometric sum) has a nice formula for when that percent is -1 < percent < 1:
a * (1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ...) = a/(1-r)

Modifying this slightly, we get:

a * (r + r^2 + r^3 + ...) = a/(1-r) - a

100 / (1 - 0.05) - 100 = 100 / .95 - 100 = 10000/95 - 100, which is around 5.26315789474

Comment: So if I follow, then with a 98% chance of success, I would write this as 100 / (1 - 0.02) - 100 = 100/ .98 - 100 = 10000/98 - 100  = 2.040816. That looks roughly right. Have I applied that formula correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Here is some more info if you want: https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/infinite-geometric-series
Just remember that since your first term is already multiplied by a percent, you want to subtract "a" like I did above

Comment: That's 'infinite geometric series' is exactly what I'm curious about, and now I know its name and basic properties. Thanks.